# what the meaning of normalized bounding box

Tags: image-processing, classification, activity-recognition

I have read in a paper that the author normalized the bounding box in the frame.

what the meaning of normalizing the bounding box and what the benefits of this process.

Thanks in advance for your cooperation

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normalise bounding box, when you want it to refer to the same relative area in a different image with a different resolution.

If you didn't do this and transferred the bounding box from one image to another one with a different resolution, it could be that your bounding box appears in a different place or is differently sized. Usually not what you want.

Comment: thanks so much mirosval, just one explanation please, what do you mean by transferred it from one image to another (is there an example please). I meant is it transferred or emerged within each frame? thanks again

Comment: If you are using it with video, where each frame is the same size, then normalisation does not make any sense, you might actually lose precision with it. It only makes sense when you want to apply the same bounding box on different sized images.